# Amadeus Enterprise API The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'. (Parameter 'via')

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amadeus

I'm trying to connect Amadeus Enterprise API in ASP.NET MVC C#, but I get the following error:

> 'The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.
>   (Parameter 'via')'

here is web config, custom

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="AmadeusWebServicesBinding" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="AmadeusWebServices_AmadeusWebServicesPort">
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10" />
      <httpTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://nodeD1.test.webservices.amadeus.com/WSAPHERE"
    binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="AmadeusWebServices_AmadeusWebServicesPort"
    contract="Amadeus_API.AmadeusWebServicesPT" name="AmadeusWebServicesPort" />
</client>
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

How did you determine what binding configuration you needed? Was this a guess, generated by some tool, or specified by documentation?

It would make sense that since there are both `httpTransport` and `httpsTransport` binding elements, then [`httpsTransport`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/httpstransport) would be the one to use, since your service URL is an https address.

Comment: Hi Tom,
This code was generated after adding WSDL as a reference in project and matches Amadeus docs.
but didn't work
I'll try to change httpTransport to httpsTransport

Comment: Are you able to share the WSDL? I'd be interested to see what it says about the service and whether it specifies unsecured HTTP. It is also sometimes the case that Add Service Reference is not completely accurate for what a service actually requires, so this might be one of those cases where it simply generates config that's wrong.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your help your I must used httpsTransport 
but I still facing other errors